# Java File Reading Incorrectly

Tags: java, arrays, string, file-io

So I am reading from a file hurricane information, the format of the information is belown

1980 Aug    945  100     Allen

1983 Aug    962  100     Alicia

1984 Sep    949  100 Diana

1985 Jul    1002 65 Bob

Here is the code for my arrays to hold the data and the while loop to read the file

```
int arrayLength = 59;
String [] year = new String[arrayLength];
String [] month = new String[arrayLength];
String [] pressure = new String[arrayLength];
String [] month = new String[arrayLength];

File fileName = new File("hurcdata2.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);

int index = 0;
    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        year[index] = inFile.next();
        month[index] = inFile.next();
        pressure[index] = inFile.next(); 
        windSpeed[index] = inFile.next();
        name[index] = inFile.next();
        index ++;
    }
```

When I run this program and print out what is being read from the file I get this

Name [Ljava.lang.String;@42f7ba93

Year [Ljava.lang.String;@74cb7e2c

Month [Ljava.lang.String;@5bc8b69b

Pressure [Ljava.lang.String;@564ca930

I have no idea what is causing the program to read the file like this, the file is named correctly and in the same directory as the program.

Comment: Show us the code that is doing the printing.

Comment: how did you print?you should print like **System.out.println(year[0]);**

Comment: I think he must be printing the array inside `println` like `System.out.println("Year:"+year);`

Comment: ... Duh, I forgot to include the index in my printing, dumb mistake, Thanks!

Comment: If you want to print out an array, then use the method Arrays.deepToString(year)

Comment: You're printing the default `toString` of an array, which will print the default Java output.

Comment: The above code will not even compile. You would do better to include your actual code in your question. You apparently retyped it, wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Printing arrays / calling .toString on them doesn't do what you'd like it to do in Java. Rather than doing

```
System.out.println(name);
```

you need to do

```
for (String nm : name) {
  System.out.print(nm);
}
```

Comment: A more convinient and efficient way is to use, what is already given by the utility class [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29). For example Arrays.deepToString(myArray)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is stored correctly and for printing the data use following code:

```
int i = 0;

while(i < index)
{
       System.out.println("Name:"+name[i]);
       System.out.println("Year:"+year[i]);
       System.out.println("Month:"+month[i]);
       System.out.println("Pressure:"+pressure[i]);
       i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're possibly using `System.out.println(year)`, where this method actually invokes `year.toString()`. Since arrays are simple objects which does not override `toString()`, you get the default behaviour when printing it:

```
/* Object.toString() source */
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

You should use `Arrays.deepToString(year)` method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(year));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(month));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(pressure));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(month));
```

A similar but more expensive alternative is to create a `new ArrayList` and print it:

```
System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(year)));
System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(month)));
System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pressure)));
System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(month)));
```

Except, your program has two `month` variables, so that wouldn't even compile.

Comment: There is no need for `deepToString`; these are not nested (multidimensional) arrays. `Arrays.toString` will do nicely.